# Error when using the “find_element” command in selenium python

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, google-meet

I'm programming a boot that interacts with a google page (google meet) for this I'm using selenium webdriver, but when i run the code `find_element` in python it gives the following error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element:

{"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/span/span"}
```

here is my code:

```
import os
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from time import sleep
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver

hora = 360
driver = selenium.webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\adelson\Desktop\chromedriver")

def segunda():
    if now.hour == 21:
        os.startfile('link da reunião')
        sleep(20)
        my_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/span/span")
        my_button.click()
        sleep(hora)

while True:

    now = datetime.now()
    data = date(now.year, now.month, now.day)

#segunda
    if data.isoweekday() == 1:
        segunda()
    sleep(120)
```

Comment: You aren't calling `driver.get()` to load a page.  Does Chrome load the page by default when it starts?

Comment: I agree with @JohnGordon, replace `os.startfile('link da reunião')` with `driver.get(...)` and post back with the results.

Comment: @JustinEzequiel it worked, but it opens a chromedriver tab and for several reasons i need to open the normal chrome,  is there any way i can do this?

Comment: "for several reasons i need to open the normal chrome" -- care to give an example? Selenium is for controlling an instance of the browser opened by the driver and not AFAIK for controlling an already running instance.

Comment: See https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/selenium-essentials/9781784394332/ch02s06.html if perhaps you want to load a particular user's profile.

Answer (score 0):

clearly, the error states that it is not able to locate whichever element you're searching for. double-check the XPath you have is correct. you can inspect the element in the browser by right-clicking on it. and copy the full Xpath